# Gif image only moves when pressing buttons in java

Tags: java, image, key, move, gif

The problem is that my gif called "grrass" in the program was supposed to move automatically, however it only moves when I press a button.

This is my main class which creates the Frame and things I need to create a window:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class mainCalss {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        second d = new second();
        f.add(d);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1200 , 900);


    }


}
```

This is my method class, which contains my gif image and my main running process:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class second extends JPanel implements ActionListener , KeyListener {
    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("images/grrass.gif");
    Timer t = new Timer(90, this);
    int x = 0 , y = 0 , velx = 0 , vely = 0 ;
    public second () {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(100+x , 100+y, 30 , 30));
        g2.drawRect(x+100, y+100, 30, 30);
        g2.fillRect(x+115, y+112, 50 , 2);
        g2.fillRect(x+115, y+118, 50 , 2);
        g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2.fillOval(x-10, 10+y, 50, 50);
        g2.fillRect(x-10, y+8, 70, 40);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawRect(x-10, y+8, 70, 40);
        g2.drawOval(x-10, 10+y, 50, 50);
        g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2.fillOval(x, y, 200, 100);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawOval(x, y, 200, 100);
        g2.drawLine(x+0,y+50,x+200,y+50);
        g2.drawOval(x, 20+y, 200, 60);





    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(x<0)
            x+=35;
        if(y<0)
            y+=35;
        if(x>1100)
            x-=135;
        if(y>650)
            y-=30;

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: y += 20; break; 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: y += -20; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: x += -20; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: x += 20; break; 
        }
        repaint();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _move automatically_? Should it move when the frame is drawn first? The movement is triggered when you press the keyboard key, because you have programmed your `second` class to have exactly this behaviour: `addKeyListener(this);` in constructor + listener methods.

Comment: @hoefling My image was supposed to be an animated gif image, however, it does not move itself unless I press a key and it goes 1 frame forward. So does the keylistener affect the image?

Comment: Of course it does, because you are calling `repaint` in the `keyPressed` event consumer. When you press a key, repaint is being called once, so one frame is repainted each keystroke.

Comment: @hoefling So the repaint is effect the whole program not only the ones with x and y variables?

Comment: yur name is longer than yur question - hows about that??